# How to use companies-house 0.1.2 python API wrapper to get company filing history?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, api

I recently learned that Companies House has API that allows access to companies filling history and I want to get data from the API and load it in pandas dataframe.

I have set up API account but I am having difficulties with the python wrapper companies-house 0.1.2 https://pypi.org/project/companies-house/

```
from companies_house.api import CompaniesHouseAPI
ch = CompaniesHouseAPI('my_api_key')
```

This works, but when I try to get the data with get_company or get_company_filing_history I seem to pass incorrect parameters. I tried passing CompaniesHouseAPI.get_company('02627406') but get KeyError: 'company_number'. Quite puzzled as there is no example provided in the documentation. Please help me figure out what should I pass as a parameter/parameters in both functions.

```
# what errors 
CompaniesHouseAPI.get_company('02627406')
```

[image: my code and error]

I am not a python expert but want to learn by doing interesting projects. Please help. If you know how to get financial history from Companies House API using another python wrapper your solution is also welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using the *instance* of the `CompaniesHouseAPI` object instead of its class... what if you try `ch.get_company('...')` ?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks! This worked. Such a simple fix :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog post describing how to make your own wrapper and then use that to create an application that loads the data into a pandas dataframe as you described. You can find it [here](https://www.pythonontoast.com/python-data-interface-companies-house/).

By creating your own wrapper class, you avoid the limitations of whichever library you have chosen. You may also learn a lot about calling an API from python and working with the response.

Here is a code example that does not need a Companies House-specific library.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q={}"
query = "tesco"
api_key = "vLmk-4YxYS-QH8nMi8767zJSlcPlo3MKn41-d" #Fake key - insert your key here

response = requests.get(url.format(query),auth=(api_key,''))
json_search_result = response.text
search_result = json.JSONDecoder().decode(json_search_result)

for company in search_result['items']:
    print(company['title'])
```

Running this should give you the top 20 matches for the keyword "tesco" from the Companies House search function. Check out the blog post to see how you could adapt this to perform any function from the API.